# Logical Error; Name Search Programming Challenge Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-handling

I'm working on a programming challenge for my Intro Java class. The question is to write a programming that stores two .txt files of the most popular names (one 'boys' and the other 'girls') into an ArrayList and asks the user to type in a name and the program will tell the user if it's among the most popular. To alleviate some confusion, I am not using a FileReader or a BufferedReader.

The .txt files are in the format of "1    Jacob" in list format. This where my error pops up. If I typed "Jacob" into the program then it will tell me it's not on the list but if I typed "1    Jacob" then it will says it's on the list. Is there a way to omit all the integers and tab spaces in the list? Or is there a better way to go about this programming challenge?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class NameSearch {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        //Open files and add to ArrayList
        Path boyNames = Paths
                .get("BoyNames.txt")
                .toAbsolutePath();

        List<String> boys = Files.lines(boyNames)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Path girlNames = Paths
                .get("GirlNames.txt")
                .toAbsolutePath();

        List<String> girls = Files.lines(girlNames)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Ask user for input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a Boy or Girl's name to see if it's a popular name: ");

        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        keyboard.close();

        //Compare user input with ArrayList and print
        if (boys.contains(name) || girls.contains(name))
        {
            System.out.println(name + " is a popular name!");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + name + " is not a popular name.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use `sub string` method on the `name object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy :

```
List<String> boys = Files.lines(boyNames)
            .map(name -> name.replaceAll("\\d", "")) // remove numeric values
            .map(name -> name.replaceAll(" ", ""))   // remove spaces
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 List<String> girls = Files.lines(girlNames)
                .map(name -> name.replaceAll("\\d", "")) // remove numeric values
                .map(name -> name.replaceAll(" ", ""))   // remove spaces
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple but I couldn't figure it out!

Comment: you can remove digits and spaces in one go like this `.map(name -> name.replaceAll("\\d\\s", ""))`

Answer (score 0):

When you read from a file line by line, it will add the line as it is: e.g "1 Jacob". If you need to add the name only, like "Jacob", you need to split the string. For simplicity, you can add the following to your code:

```
List<String> girlNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String girl: girls){
    girlNames.add(girl.split(" ")[1]);
}
```

You can do the same for "boys". And in comparison part, you just need to check collection with names only:

```
if (boyNames.contains(name) || girlNames.contains(name))
{
    System.out.println(name + " is a popular name!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If deemed appropriate you can remove the prefix in front of the names by simply adding a `map` operation like this:

```
List<String> boys = Files.lines(boyNames)
                         .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and same for the other list:

```
List<String> girls = Files.lines(girlNames)
                          .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you, however, cannot modify the data coming in at that point in time then you can create a stream from the lists and perform your `map` operation and collect into a new list:

```
List<String> tempBoys = boys.stream()
                            .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and same for the other list:

```
List<String> tempGirls = girls.stream()
                .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then change the condition to:

```
if (tempBoys.contains(name) || tempGirls.contains(name)){ ... }
```